# vmware/photon with vagrant and virtualbox provider

Tags: kubernetes, vagrant, virtualization, virtualbox

Im trying to get a vagrant virtualbox  vmware/photon up and running but the most basic Vagrantfile emits an error.

```
    Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
      config.vm.box = "vmware/photon" 
      config.vm.box_version = "4.0.2"
    end
```

```
Path: <provider config: virtualbox>
Line number: 19
Message: NameError: undefined local variable or method `override' for main:Object

        override.vbguest.no_install = true
```

One thing I tried was to set the override variable

`Vagrant.configure("2") do |override, config|`

But then a full callstack is thrown:

```
D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.3.7/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load': can't convert Vagrant::Config::V2::Root to Array (Vagrant::Config::V2::Root#to_ary gives Vagrant::Config::V2::DummyConfig) (TypeError)
        from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.3.7/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:126:in `block (2 levels) in load'
        from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.3.7/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:119:in `each'
        from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.3.7/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:119:in `block in load'
        from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.3.7/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:116:in `each'
        from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.3.7/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:116:in `load'
        from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.3.7/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:31:in `initialize'
        from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.3.7/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:817:in `new'
        from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.3.7/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:817:in `vagrantfile'
        from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.3.7/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:998:in `process_configured_plugins'
        from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.3.7/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:189:in `initialize'
        from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.3.7/bin/vagrant:211:in `new'
        from D:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.3.7/bin/vagrant:211:in `<main>'
```

How do we get photonos up and running with vagrant and virtualbox?

Answer (score 0):

Day later I figured it out

The Vagrantfile from the photon box itself has a syntax error if you have vbguest additions already installed.

`~/.vagrant.d/boxes/vmware-VAGRANTSLASH-photon/4.0.2/virtualbox/Vagrantfile`

```
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-vbguest")
        override.vbguest.no_install = true
    end
```

The error is emitted when override is used on no_install = true.

`` undefined local variable or method `override' for main:Object ``

changing the provider to

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v, override|
```

fixed it